# SSIS vs Pentaho

Tags: etl, ssis, pentaho

Has anyone used both of these to provide a good comparison.  I am doing a school project so the cost of SSIS isn't an issue as we already have the license for it.

Background on whats going on.  I will be downloading about 10 years of patent information into flat files.  The result will be 2,080 delimited files.  I want a way to load them into MS SQL server all at once.  Then I want to be able to append additional files into the DB as they are released.

Speed of the software doesn't bother me much as I can just let it run overnight.  I am just looking for something with some flexibility, and more importantly fairly easy to use.  I have never done a project like this before and will be learning how to do this from the boards.

THANKS!

Comment: Never worked with Pentaho but from SSIS try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: WOW 1tb in 30 minutes is fast enough for me.  Thanks for the article @WilliamToddSalzman ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have used both in real live projects. I do prefer Pentaho (PDI) over SSIS because of its ease of use and flexibility. 
Do read a little on the subject before you start using it. There are a couple of excellent books on kettle (PDI), or you could just read the Get Started in the Help menu of PDI. The forum is a good place if you are stuck or ##pentaho on IRC.
What also helps a lot are the Samples that you can find in the Welcome Screen.
I hope you enjoy it, I know I still do. Have been using it since 2006 and am always pissed when I have to use SSIS on some project :-)

PS : use a jtds jdbc-driver to connect to a SQL Server db, it will save you some headaches

Hope this helps,

Bart

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  In the sample datasets I have been working with the flat files have been troublesome to say the least.  I can import them into Excel or Access fine but the second I try to use MS SQL Server I basically get told that I am on drugs.

So what I have to do is import data to access, then save as .mdb, then import from access into SQL Server.  Would the increased flexibility in pentaho help with this problem?

Comment: I am only asking because the data dumping program is already coded and works to an extent, obviously the way its delimiting data is the problem but if I could find something that would be able to let me fix that after the data is dumped instead of me having to learn how to code python i would be very excited.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a couple days developing an ETL package in PDI and SSIS I feel confident in saying that PDI is definitely more user friendly.  The user interface alone is much cleaner and seems to flow in a manner that is very intuitive and as such easy to use.

Comment: Even i don't agree with that, but you can check the following link for an unbiased comparison https://sqlkover.com/ssis-and-pentaho-a-quick-comparison/